# Jquery css transform scale centered

Tags: jquery, css, transform, scale

Hello guys i've got this code:

(jQuery)

```
$("#chart1").css({transform:'scale(1,10)'})
```

with this css code

```
#chart1{
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0px;

    width:166px;
    height:10px;

    background-color:purple;
}
```

It works actually very good, but it scales the hight from the middle.
And i want it to scale from the bottom to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, just add `transform-origin:bottom;` at css script